# Train NLTK Named Entity Recognizer Chunker with your own annotated data example?

Tags: python, nltk

Does anyone have a full python example of training the NLTK Chunker with your own annotated data?

I've come across these two links, but there not super clear on implementation.

http://streamhacker.com/2008/12/29/how-to-train-a-nltk-chunker/
http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/train_chunker.html

Comment: Perhaps you should read NLTK docs a little bit more. Take a a look here http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~trnka/CISC889-11S/lectures/dongqing-chunking.pdf

Comment: so to train the Named Entity Recognizer chunker *with my own data*, would I just annotate it in the format specified, and run the code on the pdf lecture?